# Replace rspirep with http-response replace-value

Tags: regex, haproxy

I'm updating from haproxy 1.9 to 2.4 and I received an error telling me that `rspirep` has been deprecated and needed to be replaced. I'm having trouble with getting the regex right when I replace it with `http-response replace-value`. As far as I can tell, I am supposed to be replacing http with https.

My code originally looked like this:

```
acl hdr_location res.hdr(Location) -m found
rspirep ^Location:\ http://(.*) Location:\ https://\1 if hdr_location
```

I'm new to regex, but I believe it should be updated to something like this:

```
http-response replace-value Location:\ http://(.*) https://\1 if hdr_location
```

However, I am receiving this error:
`error detected in proxy 'ui-broker-master-1' while parsing 'http-response replace-value' rule : regex 'https://\1' is invalid (error=reference to non-existent subpattern, erroffset=9).`

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and explain what is actually going on as well?

Comment: Consolidate into a single regex `https?://(.*)`

Comment: In regex, `\1` is refered to as a _`backreference`_ to a previous capture (group). In this case group 1. Example: `(abc.)\1` will match `abcdabcd` and `abcFabcF`, etc...

Comment: @sln I've tried implementing this and the error no longer shows up but when I try to reach the UI this is connected to (ui-broker-master-1 shown in the error), it isn't coming up like it is supposed to with https.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution. I needed to make it this:
`http-response replace-value Location ^http://(.*)$ https://\1 if hdr_location`